# How to add result of calculation to variable

Tags: bash

stdin is

```
1\n2\n3
```

I'm trying to raise each number to the power of 3 and then add the sum of them all to $count.

what I'm trying to run

```
xargs -I %var sh -c 'math stuff and increasing $count here???'
```

Answer (score 2):

If all numbers are integers, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

pow=3                           # raise inputs to the power of 3
count=0                         # whatever pre-defined value

[[ -t 0 ]] && echo "Input number and press enter key. Type Ctrl-D when you are done."
                                # show the message if stdin is console input

while IFS= read -r i; do        # read the input line by line
    (( sum += i ** pow ))       # accumulate the exponentiations
done
(( count += sum ))              # add to the $count
echo "count = $count"
```

When invoking the script above, please try to enter numbers and Ctrl+D from stdin.
Please note `bash` is not suitable for math calculations in general. The code above is a demo for a small calculation.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
powr=3 # Set the power in a variable powr

printf "1\n2\n3" | awk -v powr=$powr '{ pow=$1^powr;count=count+pow } END { print count }'
```

Take each line from input, calculate the power (pow), add to a count. Then at the end, print the total count.

Comment: Btw.: you can use `pow=$1**3` or `pow=$1^3`, too

Comment: Thank you! It works, how would I go about this if the power I want to raise it to is a variable I declared outside of the command?

Comment: You can pass variables into awk with -v. I have amended the answer to show how you can pass the power in,

Comment: No worries. If you could accept the answer, that would be great.

Comment: `awk -v powr=$powr '{count+=$1^powr} END { print count }'`